# Placeholders - For textarea input

Tags: javascript, placeholder

I've been using a JavaScript placeholder script, to support IE placeholders.

Works fine for input type = text. But how do I write an addition to the script to support textarea?

My code is :

```
function activatePlaceholders() {
var detect = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
if (detect.indexOf("safari") > 0) return false;
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++) {
  if (inputs[i].getAttribute("type") == "text") {
   if (inputs[i].getAttribute("placeholder") && inputs[i].getAttribute("placeholder").length > 0) {
    inputs[i].value = inputs[i].getAttribute("placeholder");
    inputs[i].onclick = function() {
     if (this.value == this.getAttribute("placeholder")) {
      this.value = "";
     }
     return false;
    }
    inputs[i].onblur = function() {
     if (this.value.length < 1) {
      this.value = this.getAttribute("placeholder");
     }
    }
   }
  }
}
}
window.onload=function() {
activatePlaceholders();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply query for text area elements

```
function activatePlaceholders() {
var detect = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
if (detect.indexOf("safari") > 0) return false;
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
for (var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++) {

   if (inputs[i].getAttribute("placeholder") && inputs[i].getAttribute("placeholder").length > 0) {
    inputs[i].value = inputs[i].getAttribute("placeholder");
    inputs[i].onclick = function() {
     if (this.value == this.getAttribute("placeholder")) {
      this.value = "";
     }
     return false;
    }
    inputs[i].onblur = function() {
     if (this.value.length < 1) {
      this.value = this.getAttribute("placeholder");
     }
    }
  }
}
}
window.onload=function() {
activatePlaceholders();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

textarea is not a input type. It is a tag in itself. Example

```
<textarea rows=10 placeholder="Enter text here"></textarea>
```

In this case, your code can be

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
inputs[0].setAttribute('placeholder','New placeholder');
```

Hope it helps